# How to format a date with my own time part in SQL

Tags: sql-server, datetime, datediff

I'm working on a SQL query which returns a integer which is the number of minutes between two given dates as follows

```
DATEDIFF(mi, date_one, getdate())
```

The above query returns difference in two dates in minutes but for getdate() I would want to supply my own time.

For example, consider

```
date_one= 2015-12-29 13:39:03.000
getdate() return current date and time ie., 2015-12-29 14:33:50.000
```

But, I want to change time part in getdate() to some `10:00:00.00` so that the getdate() is `2015-12-29 10:00:00.00` by passing an hour integer say `10`.

**May I know a good way to do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this function useful:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[StripTimeFromDateTime] 
(
    @date DateTime
)
RETURNS DateTime
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @date), 0)

END
```

This will knock the time off a datetime leaving it at `00:00:00.000`. Then you can:

`SELECT DATEADD(hour, 10, dbo.StripTimeFromDateTime(GetDate()))`

Comment: Thank you and I think even `select DATEADD(hour,10, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0))` would work without creating a function

Comment: Yeah for sure. This function is particularly useful when you need to limit results based on a Date which is usually passed as a DateTime but needs to cover the whole day (ie `WHERE [DateField] >= dbo.StripTime(@StartDate)`).

Answer (score 2):

This will use getDate, but let you set your own hour.  Just replace that second parameter (which is 10 with whichever hour you want).  Use this expression in place of getDate() in your dateDiff function.

```
DATEADD(hh, 10, DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, getDate()), 0))
```

You can also add minutes, seconds, milliseconds, etc. to get what you need.

Here I am adding 633 minutes to make it 10:33 (change the first parameter to mi for minutes).

```
select DATEADD(mi, 633, DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, getDate()), 0))
```

See the documentation for other value for the first parameter: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Here is how to use it:

```
DATEDIFF(mi, getDate(),  
                DATEADD(mi, 633, DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, getDate()), 0))
               )
```

This will give you the minutes from the current time to 10:33 on the current day.  Here is a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/5407

Answer (score 1):

Notice the example below:

```
select 
  cast('2015-12-28 12:15:00' as datetime), 
  getdate(), 
  cast(cast(convert(date, getdate()) as varchar(20)) + ' 10:00:00' as datetime);

|----------------------------|----------------------------|----------------------------|
| December, 28 2015 12:15:00 | December, 29 2015 20:42:35 | December, 29 2015 10:00:00 |
```

An example like the one you used:

```
with example as (
  select cast('2015-12-28 12:15:00' as datetime) as date_one
)
select 
  date_one,
  cast(cast(convert(date, getdate()) as varchar(20)) + ' 10:00:00' as datetime) as myown,
  datediff(
    mi, 
    date_one, 
    cast(cast(convert(date, getdate()) as varchar(20)) + ' 10:00:00' as datetime)
  ) as minutes
from example;
```

Result:

```
|                   date_one |                      myown | minutes |
|----------------------------|----------------------------|---------|
| December, 28 2015 12:15:00 | December, 29 2015 10:00:00 |    1305 |
```

Example on SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/6599

The reason I used varchar is to have flexibility of typing a time such as '10:15:00' or other variations of time.

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner will gives the current date with the time part replaced with the constant you want

`select cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime) + cast(cast('10:00:00' as time) as datetime)`

**How this works:**

Cast the getdate() result to `date` and then back to `datetime` to get the current date without the time.

`select cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime)`

Cast '10:00:00' to `time` and then to `datetime` to get 10:00:00 as datetime.

`select cast(cast('10:00:00' as time) as datetime)`

Add the two

`select cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime) + cast(cast('10:00:00' as time) as datetime)`

That's all

Answer (score 1):

select DATEADD (hh,10, CONVERT(Datetime, CONVERT (date, GETDATE())))

First remove time and then add 10 hours.